# Conditionally appending models to collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to conditionally build up a list of models. I.e.

```
@items = []

if some_condition
    @items << MyModel.where(...)
end

if another_condition
    @items << MyModel.where(...)
end

...
```

This isn't working. It will actually build up an array of the correct objects but when I access fields and relationships of items in the array, they are 'not found'. I tried a few other things like `@items = MyModel.none` and `@items = {}` and `.merge` but none work. I cant seem to figure this out.

What is the best way to conditionally build up a collection like this?

**Update** I would like to be able to maintain the `Relation` so that I can continue to query it with `.where`, `.first` and the rest of the `Relation` methods.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<<` will append an item to the array, so the query won't be run and instead will be appended as a `ActiveRecord::Relation` and if you use `all` you will end up with an array of arrays. You should use `concat` to append entire collections (`+=` will also work, but will instantiate unnecesary temp arrays impacting performance if your queries return a lot of records):

```
@items = []

if some_condition
    @items.concat(MyModel.where(...))
end

if another_condition
    @items.concat(MyModel.where(...))
end
```

Comment: This worked great per my original question... but now I need to add a requirement I didn't realize I needed. I'd like to be able to maintain the `ActiveRecord::Relation` so I can continue to chain `.where` methods and the like. How would that be done?

Comment: Nevermind, I just switched the `@items = []` back to `@items = MyModel.none` and its working the way I need it now.

Answer (score 3):

Your concatenation approach will result in multiple database queries and will not be chain-able which is often needed for pagination, scoping, grouping and ordering.

I would instead collect your conditions and combine at the end.  It appears your conditions are in fact OR type queries, as opposed to AND type queries which are more easily chained.

So do the following:

```
@queries = []

if some_condition
  # Relation condition
  @queries << MyModel.where(...)
end

if another_condition
  # another Relation condition
  @queries << MyModel.where(...)
end

if and_another_condition
  # Hash equality and IN conditions
  @queries << { attr1: 'foo', attr2: [1,2,3] }
end

if yet_another_condition
  # string condition with argument
  @queries << ['attr LIKE ? ', arg]
end

@items = MyModel.any_of(*queries).order(...).page(...).per(...)
```

The magic is in a nifty custom AR extension method `any_of?` for combining OR type queries using Arel.  It can take Relations, String conditions, Hash conditions, or Arrays for splatting into where() clauses.

```
# put in config/initializers/ar_any_of.rb or in lib/xxxx
class ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.any_of(*queries)
    where(
      queries.map { |query|
        query = where(query) if [String, Hash].any? { |type| query.kind_of? type }
        query = where(*query) if query.kind_of? Array
        query.arel.constraints.reduce(:and)
      }.reduce(:or)
    )
  end
end
```

Which can be used with a variety of conditions as follows to produce a single SQL:

```
Country.any_of(
  Country.where(alpha2: 'AU'),
  { alpha2: ['NZ', 'UK'] },
  ['alpha2 LIKE ?', 'U%']).to_sql

# => "SELECT \"countries\".* FROM \"countries\"  WHERE (((\"countries\".\"alpha2\" = 'AU' OR \"countries\".\"alpha2\" IN ('NZ', 'AD')) OR (alpha2 LIKE 'U%')))"
```

Comment: That's a really interesting idea. I'll give it a shot. If it will save on some queries, this might be something I use often.

Answer (score -1):

I think the answer is quite simpler.

You can initialize your collection as an [anonymous scope](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Named/ClassMethods/scoped)

```
@items = MyModel.scoped
```

which is an ActiveRecord::Relation.

**note that `scoped` is deprecated on RoR 4 BUT `all` does the same thing http://blog.remarkablelabs.com/2012/12/what-s-new-in-active-record-rails-4-countdown-to-2013 so our example will be

```
@items = MyModel.all
```

After that, chaining extra conditions (by condition) should be really easy:

```
@items = @items.where(owner: me) if me.present?

@items = @items.group(:attribute_1) if show_groups
```

Comment: Your answer doesn't 'build up a list of models' as the question asks. It is trivial to restrict the result set by chaining where clauses as all they do is AND together thus RESTRICTING (ie shrinking) the result set, and that is the opposite of what the question asks.